# bind scope variable values with one time loaded index page angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a navigation bar on the page with an option login/signup. I want to achieve that when a user logged in successfully change an option "Login/signup" to "username". For this i am taking a variable ("session") value as false initially after successfully logged in I changed it true and also getting username. Then I have used ng-show directive to show an option when the variable "session" value gets true. But I don't know the session value doesn't get bind in index.php page which get load very first time when application runs. Here is the code of index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Read Products</title>

        <!-- include material design CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/materialize/css/materialize.min.css" />

        <!-- include material design icons -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- custom CSS -->
        <style>
            .width-30-pct{
                width:30%;
            }

            .text-align-center{
                text-align:center;
            }

            .margin-bottom-1em{
                margin-bottom:1em;
            }
            #start-button, #login-button {
                background-color: #f3989b;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: 400;
                height: 70px;
                line-height: 70px;
                width: 260px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="productsCtrl">

        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="#/about">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/listing">Product listing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/signup" ng-show="!session">Login/Signup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/profile" ng-show="session">dfsggf</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                    <li><a href="#/about">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/service">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/signup">Login/Signup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- material design js -->
        <script src="libs/css/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <!-- include angular js -->
        <script src="libs/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/js/config.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/js/app.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
                    console.log("adfad")
                    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Here is the code of app.js:


$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize modal
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
// angular js codes will be here
app.controller('aboutCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'About';
    }]);

app.controller('productsCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "$location", function ($scope, $http, $location) {
        // more angular JS codes will be here
        // read products
        $scope.username ='name';
        $scope.welcomeMessage = false;
        $scope.session = true;

        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.logins = {};
        $scope.getAll = function () {
            $http.get("read_products.php").success(function (response) {
                $scope.names = response.records;
            });
        }
        $scope.loginForm = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'login.php',
                data: $scope.logins,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
//                var json = JSON.parse(data);
//                 console.log(data);
                if (data.errormessage) {
                    Materialize.toast(data.errormessage, 4000);
                } else {

//                        console.log("logged")
//                        $location.path('/listing');
                        $scope.session = true;
                        console.log($scope.session);
                        $scope.username = data.session.firstname + " "+  data.session.lastname;
                        console.log($scope.username);
                        Materialize.toast(data.message.login, 4000);

                }

            })
        }
        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'authenticate.php',
                data: $scope.user,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
//                        console.log(data)
                        if (data.status) {
                            User.isLogged = true;
                        }
                        if (data.errors) {
                            $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                            $scope.errorUserName = data.errors.username;
                            $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
                            Materialize.toast(data.errors.lastname, 4000);
                        } else {
//                            $scope.message = data.message;
//                            $scope.hello = data;
                            $scope.welcomeMessage = true;
                            console.log($scope.welcomeMessage);
                            Materialize.toast(data, 4000);
                        }
                    });
        };
        $scope.readOne = function (id) {

            // change modal title
            $('#modal-product-title').text("Edit Product");

            // show udpate product button
            $('#btn-update-product').show();

            // show create product button
            $('#btn-create-product').hide();

            // post id of product to be edited
            $http.post('read_one.php', {
                'id': id
            })
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data)
                        // put the values in form
                        $scope.id = data[0]["id"];
                        $scope.name = data[0]["name"];
                        $scope.description = data[0]["description"];
                        $scope.price = data[0]["price"];

                        // show modal
                        $('#modal-product-form').openModal();
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        Materialize.toast('Unable to retrieve record.', 4000);
                    });
        }
        $scope.deleteProduct = function (id) {
            // ask the user if he is sure to delete the record
            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                // post the id of product to be deleted
                $http.post('delete_product.php', {
                    'id': id
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    // tell the user product was deleted
                    Materialize.toast(data, 4000);

                    // refresh the list
                    $scope.getAll();
                });
            }
        }
        $scope.showCreateForm = function () {
            // change modal title
            console.log("asdefuhy")
            $('#modal-product-title').text("Create New Product");

            // hide update product button
            $('#btn-update-product').hide();

            // show create product button
            $('#btn-create-product').show();
            $('#modal-product-form').openModal();
            // clear variable / form values
            $scope.clearForm = function () {
                $scope.id = "";
                $scope.name = "";
                $scope.description = "";
                $scope.price = "";
                $scope.createProduct = function () {

                    // fields in key-value pairs
                    $http.post('create_product.php', {
                        'name': $scope.name,
                        'description': $scope.description,
                        'price': $scope.price
                    }
                    ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data);
                        // tell the user new product was created
                        Materialize.toast(data, 4000);

                        // close modal
                        $('#modal-product-form').closeModal();

                        // clear modal content
                        $scope.clearForm();

                        // refresh the list
                        $scope.getAll();
                    });
                }
            }
            // clear form
            $scope.clearForm();
            // create new product 


            // update product record / save changes
            $scope.updateProduct = function () {
                $http.post('update_product.php', {
                    'id': $scope.id,
                    'name': $scope.name,
                    'description': $scope.description,
                    'price': $scope.price
                })
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            // tell the user product record was updated
                            Materialize.toast(data, 4000);

                            // close modal
                            $('#modal-product-form').closeModal();

                            // clear modal content
                            $scope.clearForm();

                            // refresh the product list
                            $scope.getAll();
                        });
            }
            // delete product


        }
        // retrieve record to fill out the form

    }]);
```

Comment: can you provide a plunkr please.

Comment: sure wait for 5 minutes please

Comment: @Hardik patel It has a login functionality which needs a DB interaction and on plunker it won't be possible.

Comment: Ok, No prob. AS per my observation, i think you need to set session variable as false initially and please use ng-if insted of ng-show.

Comment: It's working in other template pages but not getting the scope variable value on the main "index.php" page.